# Filter MySQL records between two tables by Join depending on a specific column value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

Recently I've been working on a PHP/MySQL script which reads information from a database with user info and file info stored in two separate tables.

Below are the schema's for the tables.

Table1

```
UID | Username | PermissionLevel
1   | First    | 1
2   | Next     | 3
3   | More     | 2
```

Table2

```
FID | Filename | FileLevel | UploadUsername
1   | file.txt | 2         | First
2   | hand.mp4 | 1         | First
3   | 1245.dds | 1         | Next
4   | beta.sql | 3         | More
```

For the purpose of this message I have omitted the passwords column and the file title/description column, since they play no part in the result I am trying to achieve.

So far I have come up with this SQL code

```
SELECT DISTINCT table2.*, 
table1.*
FROM table2 JOIN table2 ON table2.FileLevel <= table1.PermissionLevel
WHERE table2.UploadUsername = table1.Username 
ORDER BY FID DESC LIMIT 7
```

This generates the appropriate listing I want, but does not filter the level of content shown.

Any user with a PermissionLevel of 1 should only see Files with a FileLevel of 1. Users with PermissionLevel of "2" can see files of FileLevel of both 2 AND 1, and so on.

But at the current stage it seems to just want to display ALL results regardless of File/Permission Level.

I've been stuck at this issue for a couple of days now and just can't seem to get my head around this. 
It's likely to be something simple I may have overlooked, but I hope that a fresh pair of eyes may help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand the question fully, but this is what I could make of it. You have a query that returns all uploaded files. You now want to filter that list, so it sometimes shows less results, depending on the user's permission level. Please note that this user is the active user on the website, who is not necessarily the same user who uploaded a file, so this condition does not work on the `table1` table of your query.

A common solution to this is to have a session variable storing your current user's id, and possibly other information.

```
$_SESSION['user'] = 'somebody';
$_SESSION['permissionLevel'] = 3;
```

If you don't have `permissionLevel` in a local variable, you will have to join on the `table1` table *twice*, once to find the *uploader* and once to find the permission level of the *current user*. You also have a typo in your original query. The following will give you both users

```
SELECT *
FROM table2
JOIN table1 uploader WHERE table2.UploadUsername=table1.Username
JOIN table1 currentuser WHERE table2.PersmissionLevel<=table1.PermissionsLevel AND users.Username='$_SESSION[user]'
ORDER BY FID DESC
```

Comment: Your mention of using PermissionLevel as a variable made me think and after a small bit of tinkering I got this to work. 

`SELECT * FROM files WHERE FileLevel <= $permissionlevel ORDER BY FID DESC LIMIT 7`

$permissionlevel is based on a session variable $_SESSION['permissionvariable'] 
The value is called from the DB on login.

Looking back at it, yes I have made a typo in my original post, my apologies.

Thank you for your help in identifing my code issue.